# Should I slow down the counter at the online psychometric test in order to get more time and give more correct answers?

Tags: recruitment, test

As part of a selection before an interview for a position in a bank, I need to undergo a psychometric test.

Of course, the aim of the company is to select a single candidate which will fit the best the position : so the aim isn’t to succeed at the test but to get the highest score among all others.

The test is to be completed remotely (I mean from home) on a website. One of the requirement is you have 6 minutes to complete it and there’s so much question that you should answer 2 questions per second in order to finish the test… At that speed, you have course no time to think at which is the correct answer if the result isn’t clear immediately.

One of the characteristics of the test is the time limit is clearly performed on the client side (and that on server side they have just the number of questions answered). Of course, I already know that cheating is bad and that lying at telling it’s the exact thing I want to do ([whereas it barely satisfies what I need for my apprenticeship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/137890)) is bad.
Nothing is spoken or captured through video. It’s only about reading and writing.

But as this is for a computing position in a [deprived job market](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/137890), **should I instead expect that almost everyone** [will perform the trick which allows to slow down the counter](https://superuser.com/questions/1391174/how-to-multiply-sleep-timings-for-a-specific-program-on-windows-or-linux) and thus multiply the allowed time to complete by 20× since a second as measured on the computer would take 20 seconds in reality ?

After this selection step, I have good reasons to think with my experience I would succeed at the interview (which is the last step as selection).

Comment: "2 questions per second" you got something very wrong. 500ms per question is maybe testing your automation skills, but I would not rely on a human even being able to make *no decision at all* and press a *single* button that fast.

Comment: @nvoigt I tried the test for one of the position. If you click once per second you fail the test.

Comment: @JMK yes, but this won’t prevent completetion. This wouldn’t be the first time I does such thing and the human behind fails to spot the time spent as not normal.

Comment: @dwizum Cheating at the exam is bad, but cheating for getting a job won’t result me in losing my Master degree if spotted years laters.

Comment: @Upper_Case then my duty is to provide the result which would be possible normally. I have experience in providing randomization on fake voting in voting systems *(though that time it was on behalf of the company I was working for which was several years ago)*.

Comment: @dwizum well it’s not as if I could afford to find an other job elsewhere. And again, one should assume everyone else knows the trick. So the point is if they cheat I won’t be able to compete.

Comment: @nvoigt it’s a psychometric test, not a test with questions related to the future job. The job is a specialized management job which requires to know how this work technically.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs but judjing by looking at the request inspector, I don’t think it’s the case. It wouldn’t be the first time I slow down the counter at this type of test (though last time it wasn’t for getting a job). I already know someone working in the department : he is partially in charge of **outsourcing** ɪᴛ tasks of the company in **India**.

Comment: @user2284570 Patricia's answer just gives an *example* of where you'd be *highly likely* to get caught. We have no way to know whether this is the scenario you're dealing with. If you want to discuss either the viability or morality of cheating, you're probably on the wrong site.

Comment: I think if you such a clever guy with a lots of ideas about cheating, maybe you are better off looking for a job where they try to identify cheaters? After all, none better than a cheater to recognise other cheaters. Plus, you use your skills in a positive way.

Comment: One more thing. You seem to work hard to justify your decision to cheat. It seems you have already made up your mind. Why do you ask us? What is your goal?

Comment: @DJClayworth then spending 1 hour on a 6 minutes test would be definitely an issue. But what about 10 to 15 minutes instead? This isn t the first time I slow down the counter on a test with start and end time recorded server side.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs not completely a part of the question is on wether I should expect other applicants to cheat given the starved job market for apprenticeship in the country. If not, the decision to not cheat might be relevant. finding such cheaters in IT might form a job which would match my master degree but it goes down to the first issue https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/137890

Answer (score 8):

**Don't cheat.**

There's a good chance that you'll get caught, and even if you don't get caught, it's bad policy.  Trying to build a career on lies will come back to bite you.  Even if it doesn't bite you with this position, it will bite you eventually.  Better to start as you mean to go on.

You note the possibility that others will also be cheating.  That's true.  If they cheat and the company is good at catching such things, then those competitors have been eliminated, and your chances get better.  If they cheat and the company is not good at catching such things, then the only way to compete is to cheat... in which case it becomes a question of who cheated hardest.  It also suggests some unfortunate things about the likely makeup of the employees at the company in question.  Going into a job at a bank that's predisposed towards cheaters and corruption is not likely to end well.

Comment: The truth is I have to pick up a meh job. The point is I think I will be one of the lone guy at being honest.

Comment: "the only way to compete is to cheat" I would argue that's not inherently true. The test is likely a way to weed out very poor candidates. The *real* decision, from among the good candidates, is made based on the interview and the rest of the hiring process. In other words, **you don't need to get *the best* score, you just need to do well.** Cheating in order to get THE BEST POSSIBLE score is likely a complete folly, since the best possible score may not really be any better than the score you can get by not cheating, in terms of your chances at the job.

Comment: @dwizum it’s perfectly written the test is a step to select applicants which don’t need to be interviewed. Also, remember the interview isn’t about getting things in short timing. In the way I plan to cheat, I will still need to give the correct answers.

Comment: @user2284570 "the aim isn’t to succeed at the test but to get the highest score among all others" - that suggests that you must get *the highest* score.  "must get an adequate score and then do well on the interview" is a very different situation.

Comment: @BenBarden yes but true, this isn’t about getting an adequate score (so well not the highest), but one high enough compared to other which will allow reaching the interview selection step. So the aim is really to perform better than most of everyone else whether they cheat or not.

Comment: @user2284570 do you know what the scoring threshold is for the test? Do they only take the top 5% of scores? Or do they take the top 99%? It seems like you're making a lot of assumptions about how the system works without many hard facts.

Comment: @dwizum I recognize I don’t even know the number of applications rejected before the test.

Answer (score 7):

Robert A. Heinlein's book "Space Cadet" has some boys being tested for admission to a space academy. One of the tests requires them to put a bottle on the floor, shut their eyes, and try to drop beans into it one at a time by remembering where it is. The hero, Matt, only gets one bean in. Other candidates did much better. He asked what there was to stop people from cheating, and was told "Nothing at all.".

> Matt left, grumbling. It did not occur to him that he might not know
>   what was being tested.

The book was published in 1948, so the idea of an easily cheated test as filter to select people who do not cheat is even older than I am.

The test you describe could be looking for either or both of two habits that would be negative for a bank computing person:

1. Cheating.
2. Cutting corners and entering guesses without thinking.

Either of those would result in a lot of answered questions, with more correct answers in the first case. Careful non-cheaters, the ideal bank computing people, would get a few answers but most of those would be correct.

Of course, the bank's recruitment people may just be stupid.

Comment: This is a very real possibility. Banks are **highly** motivated to find IT people who are honest. IT departments in banks are generally **highly** audited and monitored. Cheating on an entrance exam for a bank IT position is setting yourself up for disappointment.

Comment: I passed the test for one of the 2 positions honestly, and I was rejected. So it’s not about highlighting who cheat.

Comment: @user2284570 It's a mistake to assume you understand 100% of what is being examined in this test. That's *exactly* what the example in this answer illustrates. For all you know, for the previous position you were out-scored by another applicant who *also* did not cheat, or that candidate did not cheat and was better qualified besides. The key is that *it will be obvious that you cheated in this way*.

Answer (score 3):

You seem interested in approaching this question without any concerns of the ethics or possible negative impacts of cheating - only with concern over competing against other candidates. I think you've already received good answers and comments that address ethical concerns or negative impacts, so I am going to address the point you seem stuck on. In a comment, you said:

> So the point is if they cheat I won’t be able to compete.

Generally, that is not true - if, by "compete," you mean "have a chance at getting the job."

Employers use several tools during the hiring process, for different purposes. But ultimately, it's a combination of these different tools that helps them make hiring decisions. Having **THE BEST** result from one single selection tool may not be an important factor in the final decision, especially for something like a psychometric test. **Generally, these tests are used to weed out very poor candidates** and as long as your score is not terrible, there is no significant impact to the process by making it better.

That said, if you're able to get a *good* score without cheating, then cheating to get a *great* score may make zero difference in terms of actually getting the job. So - cheating basically leads to **no tangible advantage** but comes at the cost of **huge risks.**

Comment: Except that the questions aren’t related to the job, and that I’m find on those type of interviews. This is just to better reach the next step. **And of course, I can only get a bad score at the test**. I already got my application rejected at the first position (where I was honest).

Comment: Consider that if the employer is using a test, they consider it important, even if you do not understand how the questions relate to the job duties. At any rate, do you know it was actually because of the test that you were rejected, and not another reason? Have you considered trying to study, or learn material, in order to do better? If you applied honestly and were rejected, it probably means you were not a good fit - rather than cheating to try to get in to the job, what about applying for jobs where you are naturally a better fit?

Comment: I could had got my application rejected before reaching the test, the recruiting process clearly specify rejections happens after each steps. So if it was for an other reason, I would have received the message before being invited to pass the test.

Comment: @Niko1978 then it goes back at making a reasonable 6 minutes score.

Answer (score 1):

That test is designed to put you under time pressure. They've surely designed it so nobody can answer all the questions. And, they've designed it to measure your "fast" thinking (cf Thinking Fast and Slow by Danny Kahneman).

They're surely measuring something other than the absolute number of "correct" answers. If you somehow defeat the time pressure factor, **they will know.**

You are probably wise **not to try to game** this kind of psychometric test; certainly not if you don't know what it measures.

As you assess whether this is the company for you, obviously, take into account the fact that their HR people have a green light to use this kind of test on candidates. Is that a good sign about company culture, or bad?

Comment: In the first test, I defeated the time pressure problem without cheating, but then I could answer only 1 out of every 4 questions (others would have required more time to answer). The aim at cheating is to still have a reasonable score which can be achieved normally of course. **To be clear, this is definitely not at all a job for me as it barely meets the requirements of my Master degree**, [but I’m not in a situation I can choose](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/137890).